# Removing a batch of records from Entity Framework when there is an error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, error-handling, batch-processing

I am batch adding a bunch of records from an internal system to our web database server (eBilling type data). I have a problem where if there is a data error (seperate issue), every add after that errors out.

```
        foreach (InvoiceHeader invoiceHeader in invoiceHeaders)
        {
            rrn++;
            db.AddToInvoiceHeaders(invoiceHeader);
            if (rrn >= RECORDS_AT_A_TIME)
            {
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    rrn = 0;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    string errorText = "Error in blah blah blah \n\n";
                    errorText += "Error: " + e.ToString();
                    Log.Error(errorText);
                    // Delete out bad record or entire set of records here.
                }
            }
        }
```

So the first 500 may go good, then I might get an invalid date. Nothing else gets added to the server and the logs get slammed with errors and crashes.

**How can I either clear out the one record in error OR just clear out that batch of records? So it can finish properly and we can go back and fix the errors thus adding back the missing data.**

Update: I want to be able to just log the error, remove the problem record(s) and move on. In this case it happens to be a date issue, I am not looking for solving this **one** instance, but all future unknown issues. How do I do the `// Delete out bad record or entire set of records here.`?

Comment: Validate before adding them. You say "our database" which means you know the validation constraints.

Comment: Your code seems to be able to step past records with errors. I would recommend put a break-point in the catch clause and investigate the cause of the exception.

Comment: What is an invalid date?  Is it out or SQLs min/max date range?  What is the exact error message?

Comment: I do... and I handled all date issues (or so I thought), and I still got the error. This is about not jamming our logs and crashing servers. Not how to fix data issues. I just want this process to complete while logging the errors so we can fix them later.

Comment: If you must know "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM." On the IBM i a "zero date" is 0001-01-01 SQL server can't handle that. I know this. Not the point of this question.

Comment: SQL Server can: use datetime2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a less than ideal solution, but what seems to work for what I need to move on.

```
        foreach (InvoiceHeader invoiceHeader in invoiceHeaders)
        {
            rrn++;
            if (rrn >= RECORDS_AT_A_TIME)
            {
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    rrn = 0;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    string errorText = "Error in blah blah\n\n";
                    errorText += "Error: " + e.ToString();
                    Log.Error(errorText);
            // Throw out all of these records so we can move on.
            // Probably not the best solution, but it works.
                    db.Dispose();
                    db = new db_Entities();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's the design I came up with on my own; it kinda works but it's really not satisfying. One first improvement would be to move the processing and saving of each batch of RECORDS_AT_A_TIME items into a class meant specifically for one batch. This way the dbcontext is injected then disposed of each time; create an instance of this class for each batch, using GetRequiredService or similar.

Answer (score 0):

With your current implementation you are already processing each item 1-by-1, therefore, if an error occurs on one of them that you *can* handle then simply do so and continue processing. Also, don't catch a general `Exception`, be more specific in what exceptions your code *should* expect e.g.

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (SqlTypeException)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, I am currently adding 100 at a time. `RECORDS_AT_A_TIME` I didn't include it, but that is set to 100.

Comment: @MikeWills you are processing 100 records at a time, but your *saving* each individual record. You aren't doing a batch save.

Comment: The error happens on .Save not .Add. So there is 100 records that could be the culprit. I want to remove all 100 and just move on.

Comment: @MikeWills sorry, just re-read your code I see what you are doing now. However, EF uses transactions implicitly therefore if 1 record fails they should all fail.